# Berkshelf using wrong Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra, knife, berkshelf

I started off using a trial of enterprise chef and downloaded the starter kit, which I assume was ChefDK. Either way, I had knife and Berkshelf configured to talk to my organization in hosted Chef.

Now I've moved to a Chef Server hosted by myself. I did a knife configure, and now knife upload attempts to put cookbooks into my own Chef Server - however Berkshelf is still attempting to upload to the enterprise account.

How can I reconfigure Berkshelf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berkshelf normally uses the knife configuration, but it also has it's own configuration file which might override settings. Check for the following file

> ~/.berkshelf/config.json

Comment: It actually searches the locally directory too, but this is still the correct answer.